# Why do we need Dynamic IP, if all devices are already provided with IP address

Tags: ip, dhcp

Why there is a need for DHCP server, when all devices already have a IP allocated to them?

Comment: Where is this "need" being defined at? Can you give us some context for your question?

Comment: How, exactly, was this IP allocated to them?

Comment: Are you talking about IP v4, v6 or both? You refer to a specific type of device (eg: windows pc, home router) or the question scope is broader/general?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your statement

> all devices already have a IP allocated to them

is incorrect.  Devices get their IP address in one of two ways:

- Manually configured by the administrator, or
- Centrally managed and assigned via DHCP

In smaller networks, it's perfectly fine to manually configure IP addresses on devices.  Even in large networks, it is sometimes necessary to manually configure certain devices, especially infrastructure (routers and switches).

But when you have many devices such as PCs, keeping track of IP addresses becomes laborious and the chance of errors increases.  By centrally managing IP addresses and using DHCP to configure hosts, managing large numbers of devices becomes easier.

Comment: There are also protocols for getting IP addresses in infrastructure-less, ad-hoc networks, i.e. without either an administrator or a DHCP server, commonly called "zeroconf networking", e.g. APIPA.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using static IPs everywhere then you don't need a DHCP server.

I'm not sure what kind of environment you're describing but sometimes a DHCP server will be used to assign a temporary IP during building of a new server, then the server will pull down its interface configuration and the DHCP assigned address will no longer be needed.